# Write values of dictionary in list if non empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {
       'field1': ('foo','bar'), 
       'field2': ('spam',''),
       'field3': ['apples', 'oranges']
       }
```

and I'd like write the values in a list, but only if non-empty:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar', 'apples', 'oranges']
```

can I use dict.values() this? how do I check for the second element of the tuple to be non empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
dic = {
   'field1': ('foo','bar'), 
   'field2': ('spam',''),
   'field3': ['apples', 'oranges']
   }
new_result = [i for b in dic.values() for i in b if all(b)]
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'apples', 'oranges']
```

Comment: Switch the `if` and `for` mate, will be more efficient.

Comment: This works perfectly. But I have to admit, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
dict_ = {
       'field1': ('foo','bar'), 
       'field2': ('spam',''),
       'field3': ['apples', 'oranges']
       }

list_ = list(itertools.chain(*(lists for lists in dict_.values() if all(lists))))

print(list_)
# ['foo', 'bar', 'apples', 'oranges']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a `map` with  list-comprehension and then flat list to match desired output:

```
from itertools import chain

d = {
    'field1': ('foo','bar'),
    'field2': ('spam',''),
    'field3': ['apples', 'oranges']
    }

print(list(chain.from_iterable([v for v in d.values() if all(map(lambda x: any(x), v))])))

# ['foo', 'bar', 'apples', 'oranges']
```

*Note*: You shouldn't call you dictionary as `dict` since it shadows built-in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-dict).